# Ubuntu 12.04 External Monitor

Tags: hdmi

I am trying to hook my Samsung Series 7 Chronos to a projector, If I type the command 'disper -l', I can detect the HDMI display, but if I do 'Fn + F4', my monitor shuts off, the external monitor connects, and displays a black screen. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Your keyboard drivers seem to recognize the screen toggling, since it goes black for a while. Nevertheless, you could try turning the display on using Ubuntu's system settings:

Go to System Settings => Displays. Both your Samsung projector and the built-in display should show up, since disper detects it. In the Display window, click on the external display and try setting the screen to 'on'.

Perhaps this gives a different behaviour.